# Connect to remote Matlab: local GUI, remote code

Tags: matlab, remote-access

In Python, I can [connect to a remote kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268945/974555).

Is it possible to do the same in Matlab? Of course, I could [log in via SSH and then run a graphical Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409050/974555), but this is very slow.  I could also use the command-line version (that's what I usually do), but then interactive debugging etc. is a lot more difficult.

Is it possible to have the GUI and everything locally, but run Matlab remotely? If yes, does this require one or two licenses?

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to a remote Matlab process via COM automation. The GUI could run everything locally, instantiate a COM object and request the calculation on the remote Matlab process.

I think debugging will be awkward and it probably consumes another license.

Comment: COM, is that a Windows thing?  I'm on Linux myself but the best would be answers covering different platforms.